# How to make "virtual" translation with polylang installed (but without Polylang)

Tags: plugin-polylang, routing

I have a CPT called "domaines" (its like vineyards in french).
My site have 2 languages (french and english), configured with Polylang for **pages** and **menus** translation.

I don't want to use Polylang features for my "domaine" CPT translations to avoid duplicating posts : I want to use ACF for translations (with a condition on the current language inside the template) because there is only 3 fields to translate (and I have more than 1000 posts).

I want an URL like : www.domainame.com/**en**/domaines/my_slug
The www.domainame.com/domaines/my_slug already exists (it's my original post in french).

There is a way to create a "virtual" page on "/en/" with the same content as "/" ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a (I think) reliable solution to do that:

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite_domaines');
function add_my_rewrite_domaines() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('en/vineyards/([^/]+)','index.php?post_type=domaine&domaine=$matches[1]','top');
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('en/vineyards','index.php?post_type=domaine','top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Now I have all my posts, virtually duplicate, without any creation of pages or extra templates.

In Polylang, I've deactivate translations for my 'domain' CPT. Everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the translate of your cpt in polylang and use translated pages to display your cpt posts.  In your page template, detect if  [the current](https://polylang.pro/doc/developpers-how-to/) language is english and use your custom translation code to display those translated fields.

> I want an URL like : www.domainame.com/en/

You can set it up in the Polylang url settings and hide the default `/fr/`

[EDIT]
To display your cpt in a page template, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18762510/3596672).  Read the documentation on how to build a [custom query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: It's ok for the /en/ it's already configured like that. But I don't understand what do you want to say "use translated pages" : it's not possible to display a CPT within a page?

Comment: sure you can, check out the edit in my answer above.

Comment: Ok but I don't need to simulate an unique archive but like 1000 singles (with trailing slug)

Comment: you can display as many or as little as you want, that all depends on how you build your query.

Comment: Ok but how can I do with /en/my_page_slug for having /en/my_page_slug/my_single_cpt_slug working?

Comment: if you use page, you can make 'my_single_cpt_slug' a parent of 'my_page_slug', and you can can use different page templates for each.